# Multiple Append Changes to Existing Text in SharePoint 2013 list-Workflow Help!

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

In my current SharePoint list I have 4 Multiple lines of text fields with Append Changes to Existing Text. I need to create a workflow that will gather those notes from each of those fields and drop them into Hidden versions of each of the columns.

So for example:

Column A would update to Column A_Hidden
Column B would update to Column B_Hidden
and so on.

Can I write 1 workflow that will update all 4 fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'Update List Item' action under the 'List Actions' section to do this. Once you add that action to your logic, you can set your hidden columns to be updated by content in your main columns. See the screenshot for reference.

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

-Drew

Comment: Hi Drew! So where would I insert that logic? Here is what I have to update the first of the 4 columns: Log[%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident%]

then Log [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden%]

then Set Variable: Hidden to [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden%]

then Set Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden to [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident%][%Variable: Hidden%]

then Log [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden%] to the workflow history list

Comment: Hi AnthonyS, it doesn't seem necessary to set the values of the main columns to variables for the purpose of updating the hidden columns. You should be able to add a single line of logic with the 'Update List Item' action and place entries for each column copy within it. I've updated my answer above to show the action/line of logic.

Comment: Hi Drew! I got the workflow to work to grab any new notes made it into the Append fields to filter down into the "hidden" fields. The 2nd part I'm trying to figure out now is how to grab historical notes for workflows that already had notes attached to them

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to log any of this columns or set the variables in your workflow.

1. Create workflow on item created as well as item change event.
2. At the very beginning, add the "update list item" action as shown by Drew. It will open one popup.
3. Select "Current Item" in List dropdown.
4. Click on "Add" button. Select "ColumnA_hidden" in "Set this field" dropdown and "Current item:ColumnA_hidden(enter x2) Current Item:ColumnA" in "To this value" field.
5. Repeat 4th step for all your column and click "OK".
6. Publish your workflow and check it works or not by making changes in your list items.

Don't forget to mark as accepted answer, in case this solution helped you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, the only problem is the hidden fields are supposed to gather all of the notes made. Doing what you have above works but it replaces the data in the Hidden fields with whatever is newest, including blanks if you don't update the fields. I need the hidden fields to gather all information and store it for reporting purposes.

Comment: See the updated answer. I have updated 4th step. In "To this value", open the string builder(clicking three dots before Fx). First write the columnA_hidden, then press enter two times( or any separator you wants to add between two values) and then write the "Current Item:ColumnA". Maybe this will work for you.

Comment: I've got it all working for any new notes placed into those fields moving forward. However, how do I handle notes that were made in the past? I want to grab those as well for reports.

Comment: does this answers your question?